# ssh.net SshOperationTimeout on second connection

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I'm connecting to the ssh on a second form. When I first execute the connect() command, everything works fine. If I close the form and try to reconnect I get SshOperationTimeout after the method connect() is called.

```
ConnectionInfo connNfo = new ConnectionInfo(ip, 22, username,
               new AuthenticationMethod[]{
                    // Pasword based Authentication
                    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username,password),
               }
            )

client = new SshClient(connNfo);
try
 { 
      client.Connect();
 }
 catch 
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Error","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      this.Close();
      return;
 }

shellStreamSSH = client.CreateShellStream("vt-100", 80, 60, 800, 600, 65536);
shellThread = new Thread(() => recvSSHData(shellStreamSSH));
shellThread.Start();
```

Method to print the output of the console

```
void recvSSHData(ShellStream shellStreamSSH)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (shellStreamSSH != null && shellStreamSSH.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        string strData = shellStreamSSH.Read();
                        appendRichTextBox(strData);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {}

                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
```

Method called to close and disconnect the ssh client:

```
private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (shellThread != null && shellThread.IsAlive)
            {
                shellThread.Abort(); 
            }

            if (shellStreamSSH != null)
            { 
                shellStreamSSH.Close();
                shellStreamSSH.Dispose();
            }

            if (client != null && client.IsConnected)
            {
                client.Disconnect();
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check if first connection actually closed.  From cmd.exe use >Netstat -a and check if connection closes.   Netstat works in both linux and windows.

Comment: You need to find a better way of managing disposal of `client`, it really should be in a `using` and not cached

Comment: @jdweng Yes, it's actually closed and when its trying to connect the second time is marked as "TIME_WAIT"

Comment: @Charlieface I can't use the "using" method because I'm using multiple ssh connections to different devices at the same time, so I would like to be able to switch ssh clients/connections from a loop. Currently the ssh clients are inside custom objects which themself are inside a list of devices. This, anyway, should work because this issue is occurring in only a few devices and not all of them.

Comment: Then these custom objects should be `IDisposable` and dispose of the `client`, you then need to make sure to dispose these objects

Comment: TCP is reliable that every message gets an ACK. Time-Wait usually occurs when a connection closes and an ACK is missing. This usually occurs when both client and server simultaneously try to close a connection. One of the ACK does not occur. The fix is only close the connection from the client and not from the server. This is a known issue from when TCP was first tested in the 1970's. It is a race condition in the TCP specification.  When both client and server sends a closed connection command at same time one side does not get the ACK and connection is left in a half open - half close state.

Comment: so @jdweng how do I solve this? haha Plus, another strange thing is that if I have 2 devices (A, B) and B is the one making problems. If I connect first to A and then to B, B is not responding. Otherwise, if I connect first to B than to A, both connect but if I close the form and then reopen it, only A connects

Comment: Usually disposing the connection will work.  Putting the connection code is a "Using" block will automatically dispose when you exit the USING.

Comment: I'm already disposing manually all ssh objects I create... :(

Comment: DId you ever fix this?  I'm having the same issue but i'm doing a using.